# How can I use the full page width (\textwidth) while importing a table with \includegraphics?

Tags: tables, two-column, width

I'm in a 2-column environment. I need to use the entire pagewidth (`\textwidth`) while importing a table with `\includegraphics`.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./myfile.pdf}
\caption{Beautiful stuff here}
\label{tab:myfile}
\end{table}
```

(I have tried tabular* without success.)

Comment: Perhaps you meant textwidth instead of pagewidth?

Comment: Not sure. Want it to use the whole page (less the margins).

Comment: Interestingly, pagewidth seems to break while textwidth doesn't, with table*. Hmm...

Comment: Then yes, it's textwidth (the width of the area reserved for text). Are you using the `multicol` package as one of the tags suggests?

Comment: There's no `\pagewidth` dimension; there is `\paperwidth` (the total width of the physical page), but according to a previous comment you need is `\textwidth`.

Answer (score 1):

The `multicols` environment doesn't completely support floats; you can

1. Use the starred version of floats (`table*` or `figure*`) but the float will appear on the top of the next page:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \lipsum[4]
   \begin{table*}
   \centering
   \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./myfile.pdf}
   \caption{Beautiful stuff here}
   \label{tab:myfile}
   \end{table*}
   \lipsum[4]
   \end{multicols}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. End the `multicols`, typeset the table inside, for example, a `minipage` or a `center` environment (`\captionof` from the `capt-of` or `caption` packages can be used to provide a caption) and then start another `multicols`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \usepackage{caption}
   \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \lipsum[4]
   \end{multicols}
   \begin{center}
   \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./myfile.pdf}
   \captionof{table}{Beautiful stuff here}
   \label{tab:myfile}
   \end{center}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
   \lipsum[4]
   \end{multicols}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

#### Remark:

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{YOUR_PICTURE.jpg}
\caption{A simple caption \label{overflow}} 
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome, isn't that in principal the same answer the OP has given years ago?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd tried this already -- but table* seems to be doing what I want:

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{./myfile.pdf}
\caption{Beautiful stuff here}
\label{tab:myfile}
\end{table*}
```

Other approaches?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the only two (as far as I know) options available when using `multicols`.

Comment: Why are you setting `\fboxsep` to zero? This parameter has no role whatsoever in what you're doing.